# What is the purpose of phase matching when drawing a MO diagram?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

During the lecture, we were learning how to draw the MO diagram for $\mathrm{BF_3}$. 
I understand that only orbitals with the same symmetry labels can interact and form molecular orbitals. My professor always elaborates a lot on "phase matching," and he would draw the orbitals out.

However, I do not understand how these orbital drawings are supposed to assist me when drawing the MO diagram. How would it affect my process for drawing the MO diagram?

[image]

Comment: If I interpret correctly phase matching is guaranteed when the orbitals have matching symmetry. You are then allowed to combine them in the MO diagram.

Comment: Phase matching can matter for determining whether you are forming a bonding vs an antibonding orbital.